# Reducibility of fibers over closed points implies reducibility of the generic geometric fiber?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a proper (or even projective) morphism of (reduced) algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$. If fibers of $f$ over all closed points of $Y$ are reducible, does it imply that the generic geometric fiber of $f$ (that is, the pullback via $\mathrm{Spec}\,\overline{k(Y)}\to Y$) is also reducible? (I assume that $Y$ *is* irreducible.)

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: Geometric irreducibility is a constructible property (see EGA IV, §9, 9.7.7 (i)) so the answer is yes.